# Erase function of the std::vector

Tags: c++, vector, iterator, erase

I have a `std::vector` and an iterator that points to an element in the vector. My question is how can I delete an element from the vector and keep the iterator?

I've tried using a second iterator to find the specific element that I want to delete and after erasing it with the erase function, the first iterator becomes invalid.

Comment: Use indices instead of iterators.

Comment: So with iterators is impossible?

Comment: Well, [`erase`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/erase) "*[i]nvalidates iterators and references at or after the point of the erase*".

Comment: Thanks now I understand why this doesn't work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*I have a std::vector and an iterator that points to an element in the vector. My question is how can I delete an element from the vector and keep the iterator?*

Please note that when an element is deleted, no iterator can point to it as it ceases to exist. So, to reference it's location normal practice is just use the returned iterator from the `erase()` method. This allows use of the `insert()` method which will put a value in the position of the previously erased object.
With one iterator, just use this:

```
auto loc_after = v.erase(iter);  // since the element has been erased loc_after points to the position the erased element had
```

*I've tried using a second iterator to find the specific element that I want to delete and after erasing it with the erase function, the first iterator becomes invalid.*

In the case of two iterators the elements can be easily erased by erasing the physically last iterator first since the earlier iterator is not invalidated. This is encapsulated in a function. The returned iterator points to one past the position of the "first" iterator regardless of order between the first and second iterator.

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

// This returns an iterator positioned after where  first_iter was before being erased
// this allows the insert(pos, val) method to insert a value in the the location just prior to pos
std::vector<int>::iterator second_iterator_loc(std::vector<int>& v, std::vector<int>::iterator first_iter, std::vector<int>::iterator second_iter)
{
    std::vector<int>::iterator iter;
    if (first_iter < second_iter)
    {
        v.erase(second_iter);
        iter = v.erase(first_iter);
    }
    else if (second_iter < first_iter)
    {
        auto dist = first_iter - second_iter;
        v.erase(first_iter);
        iter = v.erase(second_iter) + dist - 1;
    }
    else
    {
        ;// handler in case both iterators point to the same object
    }
    return iter;
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> v{ 1,2,3,4,5 };
    std::vector<int> v2 = v;

    std::vector<int>::iterator iter1 = v.begin() + 1; // points to 2 in v
    std::vector<int>::iterator iter2 = v.begin() + 3; // points to 4 in v

    std::vector<int>::iterator iter;
    iter = second_iterator_loc(v, iter1, iter2);
    v.insert(iter, 9);  // inserts a 9 in the previous location of the "first" iterator (where "2" was)
    for (auto x : v)
        std::cout << x << '\n'; // prints: 1 9 4 5

    v = v2;
    iter1 = v.begin() + 3; // reverse iterator positions
    iter2 = v.begin() + 1;

    iter = second_iterator_loc(v, iter1, iter2);
    v.insert(iter, 9);  // inserts a 9 in the previous location of the "first" iterator (where "4" was)
    for (auto x : v)
        std::cout << x << '\n'; // prints: 1 3 9 5

}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer and the example. @Ton van den Heuvel suggested this in a comment to his answer, but "The problem is that I have 2 iterators pointing to 2 elements and the first one needs to be deleted last because I need to keep that position. If the second one is before the first one and I delete them backwards I will lose the position of the first one".

Comment: I've edited the answer to put the details in a function to address this.

Comment: This is really interesting, didn't know you can do things like ```first_iter-second_iter``` to store the location of the first iterator in comparison with the second iterator. I understand what you did to avoid losing the location of the iterator after erasing the 2 iterators. This is exactly what I wanted to do, thanks for the answer and the implementation.

Answer (score 2):

> My question is how can I delete an element from the vector and keep the iterator?

You can't using `std::vector::iterator`. The iterator will be invalidated by erasing the element.

But you could achieve this by writing your own iterator class that stores a pointer to the vector and an index.

Comment: I don't really know how to write my own iterator class, I will just use indices as @melpomene suggested as it seems the easiest way to achieve this for me at least. .Thanks for the answer I understand now that the iterators will be invalidated by erasing elements.

Answer (score 2):

`std::vector::erase` will invalidate all iterators at or after the erased element:

> Invalidates iterators and references at or after the point of the
>   erase, including the end() iterator.

However, `erase` will return an iterator pointing to the element following the last removed element. Maybe that is enough to satisfy your use case?

Comment: I read that too before posting but doesn't help me that much because I need to delete first the second iterator so at the moment I delete it I will lose the first one. But that's a really good observation, could be useful in other cases

Comment: In case you have multiple iterators pointing to elements that need to be erased, iterate them backwards when erasing, that will work. The canonical approach is to use `std::remove` in combination with `std::vector::erase`. See for an example: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/remove

Comment: The problem is that I have 2 iterators pointing to 2 elements and the first one needs to be deleted last because I need to keep that position. If the second one is before the first one and I delete them backwards I will lose the position of the first one.

Comment: In that case one approach is to record the index of the required element before erasing, and calculate the new iterator based on the old index corrected for the erased element(s).

Comment: That will work, but I think I will do it using only indexes only because don't want to combine them both I think it's more readable using one or the other. Ton can I ask you something? I'm at the begging of learning STL and algorithms library how can you learn to combine functions like you said in your comment above ```std::remove``` with ```std::vector::erase```. Most of the problems I solved so far using the basic things ```for/while/if/switch``` and it seems hard to use combine functions to solve these same problems without using a loop and combining different functions?

Comment: @OvidiuFirescu, I would advice asking a new question explaining your specific use case in a bit more detail, and then explicitly ask how the problem can be solved without a for loop and only standard algorithms. It will be a question that will get attention I can promise you :)

Comment: I understand but I wanted to ask you how can you learn to use these functions in a general problem (not really a specific one, any problem). I mean when you see a new problem how do you know which functions to combine to solve the problem. I usually solve most of the problems but without using functions. How can I learn to solve problems combining different functions from different libraries?

Comment: I don't know of any strategy other than trial and error. Reading about what is available is also worthwhile (https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm). The following talk was a real eye opener for me on the usage of algorithms over for loops in code: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qH6sSOr-yk8, recommended.